# A variant of TSP regarding a direct graph with the possibility of two edges between two adjacent nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I am looking for a variant of the TSP (traveling salesperson problem) concerning a directed graph with the possibility of two edges between any two adjacent nodes.
Note: A node should be visited at least once, and the two parallel edges between each two adjacent nodes are in opposite directions.

Is there such an algorithm?

Comment: @David: The paired edges are in opposite directions

Comment: @Expert: How about this solution:
You can easily reduce your multigraph into a directed graph by substituting every v->w with a v->u->w where u is a new node. Choose the weight of v->u as v->w and u->w as 0. As long as the sum matches, it should be fine, anyway.

Comment: I deleted that answer for a reason: It is entirely and utterly wrong.

Comment: This is studied under the name asymmetric TSP.

Comment: @David: Could you elaborate more on this? At least a reference.

Comment: @Amir: I updated the answer, now that I know what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the directed graph into an undirected graph.

Take every node `u` and add a new node `u'`. Connect them with an edge-weight that forces the edge `u-u'` to always be part of a solution to your TSP instance. Any substitute edge `u-v` gets assigned the original weight `u->v` and each substitute edge `u'-v` gets assigned the original weight `v->u`.

Then, after solving the symmetric problem, you can derive a TSP in your original graph by merging all `u` and `u'` into one again.

Comment: Does your answer work for any number of parallel edges (with different directions) between any two adjacent nodes?

Comment: @Amir As per your question, you have at most two parallel edges. However, I suppose you can extend this approach if you have more edges by introducing `u''` and so forth.

Comment: This reduction doesn't prevent a solution of the symmetric instance from entering a node via an out-arc of that node and exiting via an in-arc.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat It does if you force it by setting the connecting weight to a sufficiently small value. Basically you add the sum of all weights to each original edge weight. The symmetric TSP will *have* to take the internal edges.

Comment: It can take the internal edges but in the wrong direction, though.

Comment: The symmetric graph doesn't have directionality. Every non-prime node represents outgoing edges and every prime node represents incoming edges (or vice versa). Given that each node will be visited exactly once (prime or non-prime), you cannot cheat by bouncing off half of a node without visiting the other (provided all inner edges are part of the solution!).

Comment: Ah, OK. This does work, but it reduces to non-metric TSP (which takes a bunch of the symmetric algorithms off the table).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Fair point. But I wouldn't know off the top of my head how to euclidian properties in such a reduction.

Comment: No one knows how. The best known approximation ratio for metric TSP is significantly better than the best for ATSP, and this reduction is ratio-preserving.